# margin-left code only for internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, compatibility

I am attempting to code something specifically for IE since it works perfectly well on other browsers.  I want to add

```
margin-left: -1px;
```

to all IE variations by adding that line of code to the div.  I looked it up and tried this for my Internet Explorer 11 browser on the HTML page.

```
<!--[if IE 11]>
<link rel="stylesheet type="text/css" href="ie11.css" />
<div class="mini-products-list-title" style="margin-left: -1px;"></div>
<![endif]-->
```

Any suggestions to what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE: I have been notified that conditional comments do not work for IE10 + IE11.  Being capable of adding margin-left: -1px to the code below for only IE is the issue.

here is the css

```
.mini-cart-items .mini-products-list-title {
    background-color : #233a77;
    border           : 2px solid #010d35;
    color            : #fff;
    font-size        : 16px;
    font-weight      : bold;
    height           : 20px;
    padding          : 2px;
    width            : 300px;
}
```

Comment: conditional comment css have been discontinued IE10+ onwards mate!!

Comment: IE10+ no longer accepts conditional HTML. Sounds like something else is going wrong.

Comment: So what do I do now since that is the case?

Comment: @julian :simple....paste code or give fiddle!!! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor there is the css, let me know if that is enough currently or fiddle is necessary.

Comment: @julian : HTML markup is appreciated too....fiddle will make 2 of us best friends!! :)